# To use, or not to use, a Kalman Filter to detect abnormal system congestion

Tags: monitoring, kalman-filter

Placement note: I've opted to ask here on SO because none of the other candidate sites appear as appropriate. I'll be happy to move this question elsewhere.

---

I'm starting a project to build a congestion detector for a fairly large real-time message processing system.

My current thinking is that I'll measure or sample individual message lifetimes (from input to output), and use a Kalman filter to estimate the current lifetime. While doing this, I accumulate the residuals (measured-expected), and if the total exceeds a certain threshold, I trigger an alarm.

There are a couple of quirks:

- There are many types of message with considerable variation in their lifetimes. In general, for simplicity, I cannot classify messages into expected lifetime buckets. (The distribution is probably not Gaussian.)
- Over time, the average lifetime will rise and fall fairly smoothly, with variations by day of the week and by time during the day, but, for simplicity, not in a way that can be expressed accurately as a formula.

My current thinking for the Kalman filter is to treat measurement noise as zero, and to treat the variation in message lifetime as plant or process noise. The rise and fall of the average lifetime will cause false alarms, and I intend to avoid these by periodically clearing the accumulated residual total.

My questions are these:

1. Should I be using a Kalman filter at all?
   If not what other recommendations would you make?
2. The Kalman filters I have seen so far use a fixed value for process noise variance; is there any way I can use a dynamic value, based on the recent variance of the actual measurements (given my assumption of zero measurement noise)?
3. Does the idea of accumulating (signed) residuals, resetting the totals periodically to allow for long-term variation, and whenever an alert is triggered, seem reasonable as an approach?

Comment: I don't know much about Kalman Filters, but based on the little reading I've done on them, I might recommend [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) for this question.

Comment: @Clarinetist Thanks for the suggestion. All due respect to Cross Validated, but I find the maths there a little bit overpowering. If your suggestion gets reinforced, though, I'll seriously consider it.

Comment: If the end goal is to choose from a discrete set of states, such as "congested/not congested", then I would suggest using an HMM. I have used Kalman filters to track continuous values, such as positions and velocities of physical objects, in which case I can derive a process model from physics. In the case of HMM, I feel that statistical data can be used to extract the state transition matrix and likelihood functions which define the HMM. Nevertheless the Kalman filter can be tweaked to behave like the HMMs too if you choose the thresholds right.